# Mask jsoup as a Browser when downloading html

Tags: jsoup

is it possible to mask

```
Jsoup.connect("http://xyz.com").get().html();
```

as a browser call to the website?

I try to build a wallpaper download tool and experiencing problems when downloading the page form the server.

If I download the page, say with Firefox, uploading this to a server of mine it is downloaded properly...

I figured it must be some browser based script prevention which doesn't let you parse the page automatically...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting the [`User-Agent` header](http://www.useragentstring.com/) on the request. Ex:

```
String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.122 Safari/534.30";
Jsoup.connect("http://example.com").userAgent(ua).get().html();
```

Comment: thx for the extremely fast response... I was just about to poste my own solution.
Im quite ebarased that i found it so quick by my self. Sorry for bothering and thx for the quick response...

That's what did the trick for me...

html = Jsoup.connect("http://blubb.com").userAgent("Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 1.2.30703)").get().html();