# parsing html using Jsoup - returned document with robots meta tag

Tags: javascript, html, jsoup, bots, incapsula

My problem is when I am using jsoup lib for parsing a specific url, it has been great till one day my parsing has corrupted, the document that has returned had some few tags which was not anything like the old document, it had meta tag named "ROBOTS".

An example of the header in the response:

```
<head>
  <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
```

My question is, how do you think I can overcome this block? Tried using several other libraries which parse javascript as well, but it wasnt helpful and resulted the same, maybe I didn't use it right.

(I have learnt that the meta tag robots was made for preventing bots, initially for search engines, how can I bypass this behavior? How can I act like a regular every-browser client?)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't explicitly state this in your answer, but I'm assuming Jsoup is being sent different HTML than what your browser sees.  In that case, you probably need to [set the user agent header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929203/mask-jsoup-as-a-browser-when-downloading-html/6929289#6929289) so Jsoup looks like your browser.